# Mig Layout not following cell constraints

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm setting the layout of a panel that inherits from JPanel using Mig Layout, but the cell constraints aren't working like I expected for one of the components I'm trying to add. I want the components to be on top of each other, one column and three rows. The third component ends up right next to the second one instead of in the following row. What am I doing wrong?

```
roundedPanel = new RoundedPanel();      //inherits from JPanel
registerPanel = createRegisterPanel();  //returns a JPanel
lblIcon = new JLabel();

setupLicenseInfoLabel();  //sets text of and initializes registerLabel

roundedPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets " + RoundedPanel.RECOMMENDED_INSET, "[]", "[][][]"));

roundedPanel.add(lblIcon, "cell 0 0");
roundedPanel.add(licenseInfoLabel, "cell 0 1");
roundedPanel.add(registerPanel, "cell 0 2");
```

edit: I realized that I had the MigLayout row and column arguments mixed up, but even when I tried this, I still had the same problem.

```
roundedPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets " + RoundedPanel.RECOMMENDED_INSET, "[][][]", "[]"));
```

edit 2 : I added flowy to the MigLayout constraints, and things all displayed how I intended. I'm not sure what the original problem was and why wrap didn't help.

Comment: flow shouldn't have any effect, probably something wrong somewhere else - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

The number of column/row constraints doesn't matter (the last constraint is used as long as there are components), you have to explicitly add a wrap somewhere: either in the layout constraint, or in each cell constraint:

```
new MigLayout("wrap 1", ...)
// or 
panel.add(someComponent, "wrap, ...")
```

**Update**

The alternative (though unusual) approach to wrap somehow/where is to place the components in the grid as you did (missed that somehow, sorry). It should work (and does in the snippet below) without requiring anything else, the components are placed one below the other in the first column:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
JComponent content = new JPanel(layout);
content.add(new JTextField("first", 20), "cell 0 0");
content.add(new JTextField("second", 10), "cell 0 1");
content.add(new JTextField("third", 13), "cell 0 2");
```

On the other hand, setting the flowy layout property shouldn't have any effect: cell coordinates are always (x, y), irrespective of flow. So I suspect there's something else going wrong in your context, best to track it down so that it can't hit you in future.

Comment: I tried both of these approaches (both separately and together) but neither solved my problem.